# Socket.io server with https

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ssl, server, socket.io

Here is my socket.io server.js file.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var httpsServer = https.createServer({
    key:fs.readFileSync("/etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/server.key").toString(),
    cert:fs.readFileSync("/etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/server.crt").toString(),
});

httpsServer.listen(9091);

io = require('socket.io').listen(httpsServer);
```

I run `node server.js` on server and I tried to go to here:
https://example.com:9091/socket.io/socket.io.js

But it didn't work. (This site can't be reached)

When I did it like as following with http, it worked well.
(http://example.com:9091/socket.io/socket.io.js)

```
var http = require('http');
var httpServer = http.createServer();

httpServer.listen(9091);

io = require('socket.io').listen(httpServer);
```

I know we can configure it with nginx reverse proxy too but
what I want to is to setup it without nginx reverse proxy.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For starters, remove the `.toString()`.  The key and cert are binary things and expect a buffer, not a string

Comment: I removed but same.

Comment: Add error handling on your server and you may get more specific info about what is wrong.  `httpsServer.on('error', (e) => console.log(e));`.

Comment: There is not any log. I don't think this would make any log. https://prnt.sc/w46n2p

Comment: And when I ```curl -I https://localhost:9091```, it shows ```Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to localhost:9091.```

Comment: I tried to do with nginx reverse proxy first. I got this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/q/65312064/13431339
So I was going to switch without reverse proxy.

Comment: You apparently have some error in setting up your https credentials.  Not much we can do to help since we can't debug it ourselves or see anything about what may be going wrong.  It seems that your https server is not configured correctly and not even responding properly to curl.